# Change of measure s.t. stochastic process is in $L^p$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, lp-spaces

Assume a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{G},(\mathcal{G}_t)_{t \in [0,1]}, \mathbb{P})$ and $(S_t)_{t \in [0,1]}$ an adapted stochastic process (no further path properties).

Fix $1 \leq p < \infty$. Is there an equivalent measure $\mathbb{P}' \sim \mathbb{P}$, s.t. $S_t$ is in $L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, \mathbb{P}')$?

*Backgound:* I am reading a paper that poses this is true for a countable (but not uncountable) family of such processes, however without giving a proof. I am not even sure if that is true for the 1-dim case.

*What I tried:* A classical application of the Radon-Nikodym theorem. But, for a decent choice of density, I need $\mathbb{P}(\sup_t S_t < \infty) = 1$ as an assumption, what does not seem natural to me.

Thank you for taking your time.

Comment: The condition $\Bbb P(\sup_t S_t<\infty)=1$ is fulfilled if $(S_t)$ has continuous (or even cadlag) paths. The paper you mention makes no such assumptions?

Comment: Thank you, this is interesting, but unfortunately not. In fact, it is one of the key aspects of the paper not to impose this assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Consider simple case, when $\Omega = [0,1]$. In this case we may consider Dirac measure $\delta_0$ and get what you want. But new process will have nothing common with the initial one.

In general case also there's such a problem.

Comment: That is true, but I forgot to state that I look for an equivalent measure.